# Error in Data Frame when creating a plot with ggplot2 and geom_point() and stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a problem when creating a plot with ggplot2

```
> setwd("c:/tesis/emisiones")
```

`e<-read.csv("fh3pco1.csv",header=T)`
`attach(e)`

```
names(e)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJDHR.png) "VehCat"     "Component"  "TrafficSit" "Subsegment" "SizeClasse" "V"          "EFA"
 [8] "norma"      "cat"        "cat1"

```
library(ggplot2)

length(e)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJDHR.png) 10

```
vpge0 <- function(x) {(281* x^-0.63)}
```

## No Errors in Plot

```
ggplot(e, aes(x=V,y=EFA, colour=norma)) +  geom_point(size=4)
```

## Errors in Plot

```
ggplot(e, aes(x=V,y=EFA, colour=norma)) +
  geom_point(size=4)+
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x = 1:100, FE = factor(1)),fun = vpge0, size=1)
```

Comment: What are the "errors in plot"? Can you also provide a bit of your data using `dput(head(e, 20))`.  Without that information it is very difficult to reproduce your results.  I'd also advise against using `attach` at all costs... you can get very surprising errors that will be difficult to trace.

Answer (score 1):

Using some fake data since none was provided, you can do this without `stat_function`.

```
library(ggplot2)
e <- data.frame(V=1:10, EFA=1:10, norma=c('a', 'b'))

g <- ggplot(e, aes(x=V, y=EFA, colour=norma)) + geom_point(size=4)
```

Then just add another `geom_point` that contains the output of your function:

```
g + geom_point(aes(x=1:10, y=vpge0(1:10), colour='vpge0'))
```

I find this cleaner and easier syntax than monkeying with stat_function.

Comment: YEah, you are right. I was creating these plots for my Masters Thesis, but in the middel of the process it was a change in ggplot2, so i finnaly used this code:

Answer (score 0):

[image]

## NOx

```r
library(scales)
ggplot(f1, aes(x=V,y=EFAnoxE3, colour=NormaGEuro3))+
geom_point(size=4)+
  stat_function(fun = m5noxe3, size=1, colour="green")+
  stat_function(fun = c4noxe3, size=1, colour="green")+
  stat_function(fun = unoxe3, size=1, colour="red")+
scale_colour_manual(values = c("green", "blue", "green","red"),
                      name = "",
                      labels = c("MODEM 5 Euro 3","HBEFA 3 Euro 3", "COPERT 4 Euro 3","UNTEC Euro 3"))+
theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"),
axis.text.x=element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
axis.text.y=element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
legend.position=c(1,0.82),legend.justification=c(1,1),
legend.background = element_rect(fill=alpha("grey", 0.2)))+
ggtitle("Factores de Emisión NOx Vehiculos \n Particulares Gasolineros (g/km)")+
ylab("(g/km)") +
xlab("Velocidad Promedio (km/h)")+
annotate("rect", xmin = 25, xmax = 35, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.6, alpha = .2)
```

- See more at: [My Blog](http://sergioibarra.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/r-ggplot2-geompoint-statfunction-legend.html)